# css margins issue

Tags: css

I am building a page using blocks of sections:
http://jsfiddle.net/NrkTn/3/

You can see I have added margin to the section elements, however I'm unable to add both top and bottom margins, it uses whichever is the largest value.

Each section should have a top and bottom margin of 20px, making the space between them 40px, however it is showing a margin of only 20px.

Comment: [Collapsing Margins](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/collapsingmargins)

Comment: I imagine you could achieve what you want with a border? Making the border transparent unfortunately shows the background colour of the section though, so you would have to set it to the same background colour as the div, and wouldn't be able to use a background image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Margins collapse on themselves: http://jsfiddle.net/NrkTn/4/

Comment: And to shore up the last element you can use :last-child 
http://jsfiddle.net/Edkmt/

Answer (score 0):

That is expected behavior. It will always take the largest margin and not a combination of the two. [Here's an article that explains this](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/collapsingmargins).

Answer (score 0):

Margins collaspe on themselves, so that is expected behavior.  You could do what you want by changing your section CSS to use borders instead

```
#page section{ border-top: 20px solid white; border-bottom: 20px solid white; }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/SAcK8/

Another way to do what you want is to wrap your sections in divs and use padding